# Make the controller see jsp views

Tags: authentication, view, controller

[image]

My stucture is the picture. I have my login and registration in the templates folder.
the real site is in the WEB-INF folder.
The problem I am having is the controller it only see the HTML in the templates folder and not the Jsp in the WEB=INF folder.
In the application.properties file I have
server.port = 8097

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
I want to know how to make the controller see the jsp views?